# How to find character offsets in texts using python

Tags: python, string, text

My goal is to identify the matching string(s) in two aligned text documents, and then find the position of the starting character of the matching string in each document.

```
doc1=['the boy is sleeping', 'in the class', 'not at home']
doc2=['the girl is reading', 'in the class', 'a serious student']
```

My attempt:

```
# find matching string(s) that exist in both document list:
matchstring=[x for x in doc1 if x in doc2]
Output=matchstring='in the class'
```

'

The issue now is finding the character offsets of the matching string in doc1 and doc2 (excluding punctuation marks, white-space inclusive).

Ideal result:

```
Position of starting character for matching string in doc1=20
Position of starting character for matching string in doc2=20
```

Any ideas on text alignment? thanks.

Comment: why I find it 19 instead of 21?

Comment: Hi @zhangxaochen, you stopped counting at character 'g' in 'sleeping' instead of stopping at character 'i' in 'in the the class'.

Comment: 'the boy is sleeping' is of length 19, and `i` is the 20th char which is at position 19 if indexed from 0.

Comment: you are right 'if indexed from zero', then the character offset is the 20th char. please can I see your method?

Comment: @zhangxaochen, can you please show how you worked it out? anyone can index by main looking.

Comment: @Tiger1: Please try the solution I posted 5 minutes back. It worked as you wanted!

Comment: what about a line with "blah blah in the class blah blah"  it is unclear what you want so I cant' tell if @Tiger's solution will satisfy this case.

Comment: @PhilCooper, the solution from S.M. Al Mamun is sufficient.

Comment: @Tiger1: Used set to make the solution more Pythonic! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei man, try this:

```
doc1=['the boy is sleeping', 'in the class', 'not at home']
doc2=['the girl is reading', 'in the class', 'a serious student']

temp=''.join(list(set(doc1) & set(doc2)))
resultDoc1 = ''.join(doc1).find(temp)
resultDoc2 = ''.join(doc2).find(temp)

print "Position of starting character for matching string in doc1=%d" % (resultDoc1 + 1)
print "Position of starting character for matching string in doc2=%d" % (resultDoc2 + 1)
```

It worked perfectly as your expectation!

Comment: Al Mamun, thanks for the solution. It worked perfectly, just as you said.

Comment: @Al Mamum, I'm still hoping i'll get an answer that is of two-code line.

Comment: in the real doc there must be "\n" or similar to account for.  tricky since "\n" and "\n\r" (windows vs linux line endings) affect the offset in the file.

Comment: use regular expression in that case :)